# c.l.u.b. set and type of $T$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

In Shelah's book Proper and Improper forcing , what is the **type** (i.e. what is the **underlying set** of $T$ and $T_\alpha$, respectively) and relationship of $T$ and $T_\alpha$
for $\alpha\in \omega_1$ in the following snippet ? I'd know though, what is $\Gamma$, if I knew
what is $T_\alpha$.

[image]

Comment: I have seen lots of question which is tagged [set-theory] but actually asks about elementary set theory. It is a bit weird for me that this question does exactly the reverse.

Comment: @HanulJeon Why do you think that trees are not elementary set theory ?

Comment: I do not think your question is not appropriate (trees can occur in elementary set theory, thus I do not want to urge you to change tags). I just think your question *could* be tagged as [set-theory]. (It bolsters my feeling that your question came from textbooks about forcing.)

Comment: @HanulJeon I think that forcing is in the core of any set theory. Be it elementary or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-th level of the tree $T$. It’s in the little **Notation** section just before **Theorem** $\bf{6.1}$:

> For an $\aleph_1$-tree $T$, $T_i$ is the $i$-th level, $T\upharpoonright i=\bigcup_{j<i}T_j$, and for $x\in T_\beta$, $\alpha\le\beta$, $x\upharpoonright\alpha$ is the unique $y\in T_\alpha$, $y\le x$.

Here $T$ is any Aronszajn tree.

Comment: Right. What is the underlying set of such a tree $T$ ? We do not state anything about it ?

Comment: @user122424: Not that I could find, and it doesn’t seem to be necessary to have any further specifics. The notation $x\upharpoonright\alpha$ for the predecessor of $x$ in level $\alpha$ makes it look as if $T$ were a set of countable sequences, as in the usual construction of a special Aronszajn tree, but that doesn’t seem to be necessarily the case; I think that that model inspired the notation, especially considering what he’s doing in that section, but I don’t think that the notation is to be taken literally.